# How to join two new numeric columns in a dataframe using a separator?

Tags: python, r

I have the dataframe df:

```
start   end
836 845
3341    3350
4647    4661
4932    4942
10088   10098
13679   13690
16888   16954
20202   20225
```

Now I need a third column "JoinedCol" as

```
836:845
3341:3350
4647:4661
4932:4942
10088:10098
...
...
```

I don't want to use paste() as it is producing column with char-type or factor. I want to use the new column "JoinedCol" to use in R for getting the data like

```
836, 837,838,...844,845,3341,3342........ ..... 10098
```

Comment: How can JoinedCol be anything other than char or factor? "836:845" will not be accepted as a number by either R or Python. Can you elaborate? If you have the string "836:845" and you wish to *evaluate* it in R you can do `eval(parse(text="836:845"))` but then you may as well do `mappy(seq, df$start, df$end)`. Note that since these are all of different lengths, making a single column out of these sequences does not make sense.

Comment: To get '836' out of JoinedCol you would do something like (in R): `df[grepl("836", df$JoinedCol), ]`

Comment: @mathematical.coffee - it is theoretically possible to store a list object in a data.frame - `df$joinedcol <- Map(seq, df$start, df$end)` - it is probably awkward to work with from that point, but it is possible.

Comment: @thelatemail thanks, I know it's possible, but I really would never provide it as an answer unless it seemed like the user knew what they were talking about. It's way beyond the scope of this question, really.

Comment: Apparently we have an XY problem here. AFAIU you actually want to create the sequences from start to end?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't have this type of data in R.
If you join the ':' symbol to any number, the new string will always be a factor, a character or a matrix.

To retrieve data from that specific column you would have to specify which part you want, lets say with `substring()`. Otherwise you have to have both numbers in different columns, just as you original dataframe is.

---

Still, you can have your data using the new JoinedCol:

```
>DF$JoinedCol=paste(DF$start,DF$end, sep=":") #Create the new column as you say

DF
  start   end  JoinedCol
1   836 10088  836:10088
2   845 10098  845:10098
3  3341 13679 3341:13679
4  3350 13690 3350:13690
5  4647 16888 4647:16888
6  4661 16954 4661:16954
7  4932 20202 4932:20202
8  4942 20225 4942:20225
```

---

```
>substring(DF$JoinedCol,1,((regexpr(":", DF$JoinedCol))-1)) #To get first set of numbers (before the ':')

[1] "836"  "845"  "3341" "3350" "4647" "4661" "4932" "4942"
```

---

```
>substring(DF$JoinedCol,(regexpr(":", DF$JoinedCol))+1,nchar(DF$JoinedCol)) #To get second set of numbers (after the ':')

[1] "10088" "10098" "13679" "13690" "16888" "16954" "20202" "20225"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on

> I want to use the new column "JoinedCol" to use in R for further
>   getting the data like 836, 837,838,...844,845,3341,3342........ .....
>   10098

you actually want this:

```
DF <- read.table(text = "start   end
                      836 845
                 3341    3350
                 4647    4661
                 4932    4942
                 10088   10098
                 13679   13690
                 16888   16954
                 20202   20225", header = TRUE)

#create the sequences
DF$sequences <- Map(`:`, DF$start, DF$end)

#access the first sequence
DF$sequences[[1]]
#[1] 836 837 838 839 840 841 842 843 844 845
```

You should not create commands as text, which you need then to parse, as you propose in your question.